# Expression simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My lecturer stated the following however I don't really understand how the final line follows from the previous. Could someone explain this:

\begin{align}
2(3x+y)y + (2x+4y)[-x+y-2(x+2y)y^2] &= (6x+2y)y+2(x+2y)\big(-x+y-2(x+2y)y^2\big) \\
&=(6x+2y)y+2(x+2y)(-x+y)-4(x+2y)^2y^2 \\
&= 6xy + 2y^2 -2x^2+2xy-4xy+4y^2-4(x+2y)^2y^2 \\
&= -2x^2+4xy+6y^2 - 4(x+2y)^2y^2 \\
&\le -2(x^2+y^2) + 1 \\
\end{align}

Noting that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the polynomial (in two variables) is of even degree and the highest powers of both $x$ and $y$ are also even, with negative coefficients. (It might help to finish expanding that thing out to see this.)

As a result, those highest degree terms dominate its behavior. You can see the inequality more clearly, as follows:

Add and subtract $-2y^2+1$ and regroup to obtain:

$-2x^2+4xy+6y^2-4(x+2y)^2y^2=-2x^2-2y^2+1+4xy+8y^2-1-4(x+2y)^2y^2$

$=-2(x^2+y^2)+1+4xy+8y^2-1-4(x+2y)^2y^2$

Notice the first part is exactly the bounding equation, hence we need only show that:

$4xy+8y^2-1-4(x+2y)^2y^2\leq 0$

If $x=y=0$ then we get $-1\leq 0$ (true). Otherwise, we can rewrite:

$4y(x+2y)-4(x+2y)^2y^2\leq 1$

Now observe that $(x+2y)^2y^2\geq 0$ (why?), thus the term $-4(x+2y)^2y^2\leq 0$.

Moreover if we let $u=(x+2y)y$, then we have

$4u-4u^2\leq 1$, or, rewritten $-4u^2+4u-1 \leq 0$. Can you see why that inequality must hold?

Comment: @YuriyS Typo! Nice catch, fixed.